# SwiftUI Setting Initial Picker Value From CoreData

Tags: ios, core-data, swiftui

I am pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to get my picker to show the already stored CoreData value.  I want it to show on the right side of the picker as if the user just selected it.  I have tried adding `self.updatedItemAttribute = self.editItem.attribute ?? ""` prior to the picker to set the initial value but that does not build.  I also tried defining it in `@State` (e.g. `@State var updatedItemAttribute: String = self.editItem.attribute`) but that does not build either.  If I add a `TextField` prior to the picker it will set the value, but I do not want to have a `TextField` with the value just to get it to set.  Any ideas on how I get `updatedItemAttribute` set to `editItem.attribute` just prior to the picker?  Thanks.

```
import CoreData
import SwiftUI

struct EditItemView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @ObservedObject var editItem: Item

    @State var updatedItemName: String = ""
    @State var updatedItemAttribute: String = ""

    let attributes = ["Red", "Purple", "Yellow", "Gold"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    TextField("Name of item", text: $updatedItemName)
                        .onAppear {
                            self.updatedItemName = self.editItem.name ?? ""
                    }
                    Picker("Test attribute", selection: self.$updatedItemAttribute) {
                        ForEach(attributes, id: \.self) {
                            Text($0)
                                .onAppear {
                                    self.updatedItemAttribute = self.editItem.attribute ?? ""
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to this in init as shown below

```
struct EditItemView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @ObservedObject var editItem: Item

    @State private var updatedItemName: String
    @State private var updatedItemAttribute: String

    init(editItem item: Item) {             // << updated here
        self.editItem = item
        self._updatedItemName = State<String>(initialValue: item.name ?? "")
        self._updatedItemAttribute = State<String>(initialValue: item.attribute ?? "")
    }

    let attributes = ["Red", "Purple", "Yellow", "Gold"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    TextField("Name of item", text: $updatedItemName)
                    Picker("Test attribute", selection: self.$updatedItemAttribute) {
                        ForEach(attributes, id: \.self) {
                            Text($0)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked.  Thanks so much.  One thing I need to understand is why I had to change my preview return from `EditItemView(editItem: item)` to `EditItemView(item)`, and my call to this page from the previous page from `EditItemView(editItem: self.myItem).environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.moc)` to `EditItemView(self.myItem).environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.moc)`.  I do not get why using the `init` eliminates the need to call and return using editItem.  Do you happen to know?

Comment: @Arkyyn, it is due to signature of init - `init(_ item: Item)`. You can change it to `init(editItem: Item)`, and fix first member assignment, to get your previous syntax.

Comment: So, I tried that I am still missing something. I tried `    init(editItem: Item) {
        self._updatedItemName = State<String>(initialValue: editItem.name ?? "")
        self._updatedItemAttribute = State<String>(initialValue: editItem.attribute ?? "")}` but I got an error that says "Return from initializer without initializing all stored properties.  The above makes more sense to me, but I am obviously missing something.  Any ideas?  I got the other way to work.  Just trying to understand though. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Wow.  I would have never got that I needed to `self.editItem = editItem`.  I also had to change the `item.name` and `item.attribute` to `editItem.name` and `editItem.attribute'. What is the `self.editItem = editItem` doing?  Seems extraneous but it obviously is not.

Comment: @Arkyyn, updated again )), as really introduced naming bug, separated 'argument label' and 'argument' and 'member' explicitly to show 'what is what'.

Comment: Oh, OK.  That makes more sense.  So, the `_` in `init(_ item: Item)` was basically a shorthand it looks like.  If I use it with `editItem` then I have to keep that in the preview return and in the call to the page.  Interesting.  Thx!